# C++ custom comparator between std::string and potentially non-null terminated character array for unordered_map::find

Tags: c++, comparator, stdstring, unordered-map, strcmp

I know the question may sound strange, but there is some legacy code where there is an unordered_map where the std::string key is maximum size 8+1 (the 1 for null-termination).

I am receiving a string in a char[8] variable that I do not wish to strcpy to a temp std::string just for the find() call.

Is there a way somehow to implement some comparator so I can use the char[8] directly in the find() call?

Keep in mind that the char[8] may contain something like "12345678" (no null-termination) so the default strcmp probably wouldn't work, although perhaps strncmp would?

Comment: On a 64-bit machine you copy 8 chars in a single move. How much  an you (micro)optimize this?

Comment: Correct.  `strncmp(lhs.data(), rhs, 8)` is the base thing you want to use.

Comment: Are you using boost::unordered_map?

Answer (score 2):

If you map type uses a key type of `std::string` you won't be able to avoid constructing a `std::string`, independent on whether you use `std::map<std::string, T>` (see the signature in 23.4.4.1 paragraph 2) or `std::unordered_map<std::string, T>` (see the signature in 23.5.4.1 paragraph 3): the argument to `find()` is a `key_type const&`. Trying to pass a non-null terminated C-string to this will cause funny behavior. Personally, I would probably create a helper function which creates `std::string` from the `char` array and rely on the Small String Optimization being used (i.e. the characters only get copied rather than memory is getting allocated).

If profiling shows that this is indeed a performance problem, I would probably create a simple fixed size constant string class and use this as a key for my associative container: the few operations this actually needs aren't really hard to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Create a comparator class that has multiple overloads for `operator==`, taking each combination of `char*` and `const string&` parameters. Use the `c_str()` method on the strings and compare with `strncmp`.

Comment: Note that you probably don't want to compare predicates. That is, you don't want to overload `operator==()` but rather the function call operator `operator()()`. Probably, the member functions should be `const`. That said, I don't think this is going to work...